# Jquery to get the contents of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the contents of a `<div>` when a link is clicked

eg :

there are two `div` tags

```
<div id="1" > This Is First Div </div>
<div id="2" > This Is Second Div </div>
<a href="#" id="click" >Click Here</a>
```

When the link is clicked, I need to get the content as:

> This Is Fist Div
>    This Is Second Div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I well understood

```
$('a').on('click', function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   $($(this).prevAll('div').get().reverse()).each(function() {
     alert ($(this).text())
   })
});
```

As a sidenote, the `id` attributes you choose are not valid (they cannot start with a digit)

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/533qX/

edit. With one single alert

```
$('a').on('click', function(ev) {
   var text = "";
   ev.preventDefault();
   $($(this).prevAll('div').get().reverse()).each(function() {
     text += $(this).text() + "\n";
   })
   alert(text);
});
```

Comment: i need to define the div id in the script and i need to get all in one alert is that possible

Answer (score 3):

```
function alertDiv(divId){
    $('#click').on('click', function(e){
       alert ($(divId).text());
       e.preventDefault();
    });
}

alertDiv('#one');
alertDiv('#two');
```

http://jsbin.com/ebowim/2/edit

Comment: main post links is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734448/a-button-to-add-a-product-to-a-cart i need a button to add that product to the cart is that possible can you help me in this